# gsp, groovy, encodeURI component, inline javascript

Tags: javascript, groovy, escaping, encode, gsp

i have a problem with this each loop

i have a select, you choose an option, press a button and the selected value is beamed via ajax as encodeURIcomponent to the backend, the answer updates this ul :

```
<g:each in="${items}">
<li class="${fieldName}_item" >${it}<span onclick="deleteItem('${fieldName}','${id}','${reloadForm}', '${it}');" class="editdropdel ${fieldName}_button"></span></li>
</g:each>
```

as soon as `${it}` contains special characters like " "" " the inline stuff is broken,

is there something like this possible ?

```
onclick="deleteItem('${fieldName}','${id}','${reloadForm}', 'encodeURIcomponent(${it})');"
```

i just don´t get it

thankws in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this breaks when `${it}` contains `"`, because this effectively means that the value of your onclick attribute gets terminated where the second `"` occurs.

encodeURIComponent can of course not help you here, because it “comes too late” – you can not call a JavaScript method to fix broken HTML code.

What you want is to have the `"` rewritten to `&quot;` – so that it does not end the attribute value. For which method does that in your template language – please consult docs.

Comment: yeah thats my question, how can i achieve this to my ArrayList "items" in groovy controller before distributing them to the rendered view?

Comment: okay there´s no wasy way out, i have to rebuild this whole thing using JSON but thanks anyway for your support